# wrong material showing - faces show different material altough they use the same material slot

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I have an object with an image texture. somehow one of the faces is brighter than the other ones although every face uses the same image texture and the same material slot. it drives me crazy. can someone please help me figure out whats wrong?

[image: 1]

[image: 2][image: 3]

Comment: Hi Christoph...schöner Name :D ....please provide blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: Maybe you have a flipped normal? Try selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then select `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside` from the menu at the top of the 3D viewport.

Comment: Hello Chris and Chris, here is the Blend file! Thank you in advance! 
@Christopher Bennett I binged the procedural Texture vid you recommended. It was awesome! I wished the guy had a "level 2" video :)
https://we.tl/t-PitIWb1iMi